# Internal error during run emulater in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception

I encounter each time when try to run project.

An internal error occurred during: "Launching **Android_project_name**".

**java.lang.NullPointerException**
[image]

Comment: Provide your logcat traces and the source code whose lie number is indicated in those traces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be due to a lack of AVD being selected or created for your project.  Check the run configuration you have set up and under the 'target' tab, make sure you have at least 1 AVD available and selected.    Several ways to get there, but you can use Project->Properties->Run/Debug Settings ... once there, double click your project name.